# Getting Webdriver ElementNotVisibleException when trying to click on sub-menu buttons that appear on hovering the mouse over menu buttons

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to make selenium server 2.0 identify the sub-menu buttons that appear on hovering the mouse over menu buttons. For example, there is a menu button. On hovering the mouse over it, 2 sub-menu buttons appear. I want to click on the sub-menu button. How to make selenium server 2.0 identify the sub-menu button and click it?

Comment: Open FireBug and checkout the page HTML. Some divs would be transparent in it, those are the one's which are hidden. When you hover the mouse onto the fields they would appear.Fetch the required element as tag names (or your implementation) and use the .click() function.

Comment: and whenever dealing with js, give a delay of 1sec or more too

Comment: The problem is that when the page loads, the style for the sub-menu buttons is 'display: none'. How to make selenium click on that sub-menu button?

Comment: **If possible** can you specify the site url so that I can take a look at it

Comment: Please find below the HTML source code.

<li class="nav_li" onmouseout="menuOut('top_sell')" onmouseover="menuOver('top_sell')">
<a id="top_sell" class="nav_a" href="javascript:goFirstUrl('top_sell');" style="">Menu</a>
<ul id="top_sell_sub" class="nav_sub" style="display: none;">
<li>
<a href="/some_link">Sub Menu1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/some_link">Sub Menu2</a>
</li>
</ul></li> I want to select the Sub menu1. How should I do it?

Comment: you stated in your last comment "How to make selenium click on that sub-menu button?" but in the code specified there is no BUTTON.

Comment: Ah yes, it is not a button.Apologies for the mistake. There is a select/click action on the sub-menu <li> item 'Sub Menu1'. How to handle it?

Comment: Are you hovering on this element and then clicking on the submenu using script?

Comment: @ A.J, yes. I am hovering over the 'Menu'. Upon hovering over 'Menu', the two 'Sub Menu1' and 'Sub Menu2' appear and then I select a submenu.

Comment: Your code should work if you have driver.moveTo(link=Menu) and then driver.click(link=Sub Menu1)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code by Updating  findElement method's argument value:

```
 //Find the main menu element
    WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.id("top_sell"));

    //Perform mouse over action
    Actions mouseMenu = new Actions(driver);
    mouseMenu.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();

    //Then find the sub menu element
    WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/some_link'"));

    //Now click on sub menu
    subMenu.click();
```